# Vimdiff line count of different lines

Tags: vimdiff

is there a way to number the lines that are different in vimdiff? Is there a way to count the lines that are different in vimdiff?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: If you need to indicate something about the version of your vim or what is supported, you can [edit] the question body to do so; tags can be discussed on [meta]

Answer (score 1):

You can see which lines are different in diff mode:

```
echo filter(range(1, line('$')), 'diff_hlID(v:val, 1) == hlID("DiffChange") || diff_hlID(v:val, 1) == hlID("DiffText")')
```

Comment: How do I use this? When I put this on the command line this is what I see `:>echo filter(range(1, line('$')), 'diff_hlID(v:val, 1) == hlID("DiffChange") || diff_hlID(v:val, 1) == hlID("DiffText")')
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
`.

Comment: When I put this in vim this is what I see `E117: Unknown function: range
E116: Invalid arguments for function filter(range(1, line('$')), 'diff_hlID(v:va
l, 1) == hlID("DiffChange") || diff_hlID(v:val, 1) == hlID("DiffText")')
E15: Invalid expression: filter(range(1, line('$')), 'diff_hlID(v:val, 1) == hlI
D("DiffChange") || diff_hlID(v:val, 1) == hlID("DiffText")')
Hit ENTER or type command to continue
`.

Comment: @cokedude it works for me, maybe your vim version is too old?